# IOError: cannot open resource

Tags: python, fonts, io, word-cloud

I have a code on ipython notebook where I am attempting to make a wordcloud, but I get an error. From what I could see, the error is related to something else and not my code (something with fonts?)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-795b92e06f22> in <module>()
  4 #    print x[0], x[1]
  5 
----> 6 genWordCloud(list_of_tuples)

<ipython-input-70-55c34fb2c915> in genWordCloud(filename)
 15     count = filename
 16     #words = myWC.fit_words(count, width=500, height=500)
---> 17     words = myWC.fit_words(count)
 18     myWC.draw(words, pngPath + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.png', width=500, height=500, scale=1)
 19     return 'Cloud generated for {}'.format(filename)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pyc in fit_words(self, words)
177             while True:
178                 # try to find a position
--> 179                 font = ImageFont.truetype(self.font_path, font_size)
180                 # transpose font optionally
181                 if random_state.random() < self.prefer_horizontal:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.pyc in truetype(font, size, index, encoding, filename)
238 
239     try:
--> 240         return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding)
241     except IOError:
242         if sys.platform == "win32":

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.pyc in __init__(self, font, size, index, encoding, file)
135 
136         if isPath(font):
--> 137             self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding)
138         else:
139             self.font_bytes = font.read()

IOError: cannot open resource
```

I'm not so sure as to how to interpret this. Seems like a class I'm using needs some fonts, and something happens with some font files. Any insight will be appreciated

I am using this as a base: http://99projects.co/reports/p05-word-frequency/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify a font_path in your wordcloud object. Amueller, the author of [the library](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) changed a lot of things in his latest version. I updated my project according to these changes, you can [check it here](http://99projects.co/updates/u02-dealing-with-library-changes-in-project-05/)

Comment: I was looking to see what you wrote about dealing with library changes but the url didn't work any more. Oh, the irony ^^

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac OS X, I've got the error:

```
IOError: cannot open resource
```

I changed the FONT_PATH in the file "wordcloud.py"

```
FONT_PATH = os.environ.get("FONT_PATH", "/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman.ttf")
```

And the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac OS X, I've got the error:

```
IOError: cannot open resource
```

I changed the FONT_PATH in the file "xxx.py"

```
 wc = WordCloud(
    max_words=100,
    width=2000,
    height=1200,
    font_path = 'Hiragino Sans GB.ttc'
)
```

It can goes right!